# How to limit the json reponse for display in Angular 11?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, spring-boot, angular11

I have requirement where I have an Angular web application with Spring boot Module.

Spring boot communicates with REST API and provides response to Angular web application.

So, the REST API sending large JSON array of objects and I have to display json in a grid. I have to display `maximum 1000 rows` of the data.

Since I can't make changes in the server side, how can I limit the size of the data for display?

Comment: Can you add the data structure in the question code? What you want to show and how you want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

const dataToDisplay = incomingData?.slice(0, 1000);